# Upgrading to Drupal 10

Tags: drupal

I am using the latest CiviCRM on a Drupal 9 site, currently. As that Drupal version is no longer supported, we need to update the underlying CMS to Drupal 10. Are there special update instructions for a Drupal site with regards to CiviCRM?

I did find some documentation about CiviCRM compatility with Drupal 10 (seems mostly ready:  https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/drupal/-/issues/176 ). Drupal documents the numerous steps required (https://www.drupal.org/docs/upgrading-drupal/upgrading-from-drupal-8-or-later/how-to-upgrade-from-drupal-9-to-drupal-10) but especially with the additional civicrm requirements, in my first attempt composer was struggling to resolve the various version requirements.

Are there any important aspects to keep in mind? Or tips to get this done smoothly?

Comment: It's better if you post the specific problem. E.g. what is the error composer gives?